# create a dictionary with a .txt file in python

Tags: python, dictionary

I have a list of pairs like `pair_users = [('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('e','d'), ('e','f')]` when I saved this I used this code:

```
with open('pair_users.txt', 'w') as f:
  f.write(','.join('%s' % (x,) for x in pair_users))
```

Then, when I want to use it in another notebook to create a dictionary which will look like this `{'a': ['b', 'c'], 'b': [], 'c': [], 'd': [], 'e': ['d', 'f'], 'f': []}`

to create that dictionary I am using this code:

```
graph = {}
for k, v in pair_users:
    graph.setdefault(v, [])
    graph.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

graph
```

but my problem is when I run the graph code after opening the file I saved `pair_users = open('/content/pair_users.txt', 'r')` the result I get is an empty dictionary `{}`.

This is the output I have when I open the file

[image]

When I use the code to create the graph without saving the list as txt file I get the right answer, my problem is when I save it and then I open it.

Here it worked for example:

[image]

Thanks in advance for your ideas!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apart from using `pickle` or parsing the string as proposed in the other answeres, you can use some "more universal format", e.g. JSON:

```py
import json

pair_users = [('a','b'), ('a','c'), ('e','d'), ('e','f')]
with open('pair_users.txt', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(pair_users,f)

with open("pair_users.txt") as f:
    pair_users = json.load(f)

graph = {}
for k, v in pair_users:
    graph.setdefault(v, [])
    graph.setdefault(k, []).append(v)
print(graph)
```

Answer (score 1):

- The issue is, `pair_users` is a `str` type when it's read back in.
- Use [`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html#ast.literal_eval) to convert the `string` to a `tuple`.

```py
from ast import literal_eval

pair_users = open('test.txt', 'r')

pair_users= literal_eval(pair_users.read())

graph = {}
for k, v in pair_users:
    graph.setdefault(v, [])
    graph.setdefault(k, []).append(v)

graph
[out]: 
{'b': [], 'a': ['b', 'c'], 'c': [], 'd': [], 'e': ['d', 'f'], 'f': []}
```

Answer (score 1):

The result you get when you read the file is just a single string. You cannot iterate the string as `k,v`.
You could either parse the string into tuples by your own parsing or you could go with an option like [`pickle`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pickle.html#:%7E:text=%E2%80%9CPickling%E2%80%9D%20is%20the%20process%20whereby,back%20into%20an%20object%20hierarchy.).

With pickle it is :

```
import pickle
with open('pair_users.pkl', 'wb') as f:
    pickle.dump(pair_users, f)
    f.close()

with open('pair_users.pkl', 'rb') as f:
    pair_tuple = pickle.load(f)
    f.close()
    print(pair_tuple)
```